# Having output of for loop get a different name after each run in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I want after each run of `for` loop, the output of `for` loop is stored as a name comprised of `p` with `1:i` attached to `p`.

For example, at run 1 of `for` loop, I want the output of `for` loop to be named `p1`, at run 2, `p2`, and so on. So, after `i` runs, we will have `p1, p2, ..., pi` objects.

I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this?

(***Note:*** My ultimate goal is to subtract `p1, p2, ..., pi` **Pair-Wise** from each other **within the `prop` function**.)

```
prop <- function(n, yes, a, b){

 p = numeric(length(n))      

for(i in 1:length(n)){  
p[i] <- rbeta(1e6, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `p <- vector("list", length(n))` and inside the `for` loop `p[[i]] <-`  It is better not to create multiple objects in the global env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it the one you are looking for ?

```
prop <- function(n, yes, a, b){
  p <- list() 
  for(i in 1:length(n)){  
    p[[i]] <- rbeta(1e6, a[i] + yes[i], b[i] + (n[i] - yes[i]))
  }
  names(p) <- paste("p",n,sep = "")
  return(p)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `assign` function can be used to Assign a value to a name in an environment.

**Usage**

```
assign(x, value, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),
       inherits = FALSE, immediate = TRUE)
```

It can be used as :

```
prop <- function(n, shape1, shape2, ncp){
  sol <- list()
  for(i in 1:n){
    p_var <- paste0("p", i)
    x <- rbeta(n, shape1[i], shape2[i], ncp[i])
    assign(p_var, x, envir = as.environment(.GlobalEnv))
    sol[[p_var]] <- get(p_var)
  }
  sol
}
n=3;shape1=c(1,2,3);shape2=c(4,5,6);ncp=c(0.1,0.2,0.3)
```

Now `prop` function will return named list as well as create objects `p1`,`p2`,`p3`

```
> out <- prop(n, shape1, shape2, ncp)
> out
$p1
[1] 0.33343059 0.01592913 0.08372019

$p2
[1] 0.2380992 0.1766112 0.1967696

$p3
[1] 0.27451031 0.23409990 0.06519348

> p1
[1] 0.33343059 0.01592913 0.08372019
> p2
[1] 0.2380992 0.1766112 0.1967696
> p3
[1] 0.27451031 0.23409990 0.06519348
```

Hope my understanding of your problem is clear.